# Use of Output cache on Page Controllers Page Action Method Tridion SIte 9.1

Tags: dxa, sites-9.1, caching

We are using Tridion site 9.1 and DXA. recently we are noticing high CPU Usage and site down alert on production. Is it good idea to cache the whole page action response and serve the cached page (content editors can wit for 5 mins to reflect their changes). Also in my understanding using "OutputCacheLocation.Server" will save the cache in server, then will it increase CPU utilization as the cache is going to be save in server?

```
    [OutputCache(NoStore = false, Duration = 300, VaryByParam = "*", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
 public override ActionResult Page(string pageUrl)
        {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you already mention the down-side of (time-based) caching, this almost sounds like a rhetorical question. Although I would say that the impact of in-process, server-side caching is mostly on memory footprint rather than on CPU utilization.

Furthermore, you have to realize that (parts of) your page may be too dynamic to store in a time-based cache and you may want to use "donut caching" in order to keep those dynamic parts up-to-date.